# MLE of $\theta$ when $f(x, \theta) = c \theta^c x^{-(c + 1)}$, $x \geq \theta$; $c$ constant > 0; $\theta > 0$

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood, constraints

Let $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ denote a sample from a population with density $\theta$ when $f(x, \theta) = c \theta^c x^{-(c + 1)}$, $x \geq \theta$; $c$ constant > 0; $\theta > 0$.

I came up with a solution to this problem, but it seems a bit iffy so I thought I'd ask the community.

The likelihood of this sample is
\begin{align}
L_{X_1, \ldots, X_n}(\theta) & = c^n \theta^{nc} \left(\prod_{i=1}^n X_i \right)^{-(c + 1)} \prod_{i=1}^n 1(X_i \geq \theta), \\
& = c^n \theta^{nc} \left(\prod_{i=1}^n X_i \right)^{-(c + 1)} 1(X_{(1)} \geq \theta).
\end{align}

For $X_{(1)} < 0$ the likelihood is 0. For $X_{(1)} \geq 0$, the likelihood is proportional to $\theta^{nc}$ and it is increasing in $\theta$, but the maximum value that $\theta$ can attain on $(0, X_{(1)}]$ is at the right boundary point. Hence the MLE of $\theta$ is $X_{(1)}$.

Is this correct? If yes, is there a more principled way of solving this type of problems that don't require analyzing the function itself? Furthermore, if the constraint was of type $X_i > \theta$, then the MLE wouldn't exist?

Comment: I think the factor $\mathbb{1}(X_{(1)}>0)$ should be $\mathbb{1}(X_{(1)}>\theta)$

Comment: Edited! Thanks.

Comment: You are maximizing, except that the function (in terms of $\theta$) is not differentiable everywhere (there is a sump at the *end point* $X_{(1)}$. The MLE estimator in this case is $\hat{\theta}=X_{(1)}$.

Comment: Thank you. I understand.